# Accessing MODIS subdatasets from the command line?

Tags: modis, gdal-translate, hdf, gdal-calc, shell

FYI I'm new to command-line geospatial operations. I'm working with the MODIS BRDF-Albedo Quality product (MCD43A2) and am trying to:

1) do a simple `gdal_calc.py` operation to mask certain QA values in 100s of .hdf4 files

2) use these masks in the 'mask' option  in `gdal_translate` to create .tiff files.

I can access the subdatasets of one hdf file in the command line with:

`gdalinfo -sd 1 MCD43A2.A2013225.h12v09.005.2013234130154.hdf`

^ This prints the information, but I need to be able to reference this subdataset in the `subdataset_band1.hdf` portion of the `gdal_calc` expression below:

`gdal_calc.py -A subdataset_band1.hdf --outfile=subdataset_band1_mask.hdf --calc=“1*(A<3)”`

How can I reference or save a single subdataset to access in the input file of the `calc` command?

Note: I'm trying to avoid first creating .tiffs of the QA, *then* creating the masks, *then* applying them in a gdal_translate with other .hdf files -- I plan to apply .hdf masks to other .hdf files in step 2 above... suggestions for more efficient ways to do this welcome!